# Как сделать две параллельно работающих сети?

Tags: сеть, wifi, lan

Есть ПК с сетевой картой и Wi-Fi адаптером, с помощью которого происходит соединение с Wi-Fi сетью, которую раздаёт роутер на входе в квартиру. 
И есть принтер, который подключается по витой паре в локальную сеть.

На данный момент нет возможности провести витую пару от роутера на входе к принтеру или ПК, но есть возможность соединить ПК и принтер.

Как мне настроить сети таким образом, чтобы принтер и ПК видели друг друга по локальной сети, а интернет-подключение ПК осуществлялось через Wi-Fi адаптер?

Comment: ПК надо настроить так, чтобы он стал маршрутизатором между портом витой пары и Wi-Fi-адаптера. Для этого в окне "Сетевые подключения" надо выделить оба подключения, нажать на любое из них правой кнопкой мыши и выбрать пункт "Настройка моста". Если озвучите версию операционной системы, то я смогу сказать, как попасть в то окно.

Comment: @Arhad-the-dev можете написать как ответ, я помечу правильным. Спасибо!

Comment: @Arhad-the-dev проблема возникла, интернет периодически отваливается, у беспроводной сети статус "проверка на подлинность" иногда появляется. Я так понимаю, какой-то конфликт происходит, как решить?